# JSP tag attributes with different value types

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

Is it possible to have a JSP tag with different value types for its attributes?

```
<tag>
    <name>init</name>
    <tag-class>com.example.InitTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>locale</name>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>

public class InitTag extends SimpleTagSupport {
    private Locale locale;

    public InitTag() {
        setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    }

    public void setLocale(String locale) {
        setLocale(SetLocaleSupport.parseLocale(locale));
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to be able to use a Locale object as well as a String object as attribute value:

```
<mytag:init locale="en" />
or
<mytag:init locale="${anyLocaleObject}" />
```

But getting this exception: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "en" to class "java.util.Locale" for attribute "locale": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager`

Do I have to use this mentioned "Property Editor"? How to use it then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use an attribute of type Object and dynamically check if it's String or Locale or whatever.

Comment: I could, but isn't there any clean and type safe way?

Comment: @dtrunk I don't know, maybe someone can answer better. Did you try using a String attribute and check if Locale will be converted to String? Though it won't be much more type-safe than Object.

Comment: Yes, I did. It works well. I'll wait a day and if no better answer will be provided I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

How about this

```
<tag>
    <name>init</name>
    <tag-class>com.example.InitTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>empty</body-content>
    <attribute>
        <name>localeCode</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
    <attribute>
        <name>locale</name>
        <required>false</required>
        <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
    </attribute>
</tag>

public class InitTag extends SimpleTagSupport {

    private Locale locale;

    public InitTag() {
        setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
    }

    public void setLocaleCode(String locale) {
        setLocale(SetLocaleSupport.parseLocale(locale));
    }

    public void setLocale(Locale locale) {
        this.locale = locale;
    }
}
```

In JSP

```
<mytag:init localeCode="en" />
OR
<mytag:init localeCode="{anyLocaleCode}" />
OR
<mytag:init locale="${anyLocaleObject}" />
```

Comment: Nice idea but that wouldn't answer the question how to use one attribute with different value types.

Comment: Ok, I gues this is true. Thank you!